# How do I compile boost into a .a library for use in an xcodeproj?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, boost

I currently have a file called `libboost_serialization.a` left over from another developer, but when I try to compile I get `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:` and a ton of errors. I'm assuming this is because the `.a` file has been built for 32 bit, not 64, so I'm trying to recompile boost for 64 bit.

I'm having trouble, though. I've came across many guides like [this](http://www.neuraladvance.com/compiling-boost-on-mac-os-x.html) that go over how to get boost installed onto your system, but nothing on compiling boost into a `.a` for use in a project. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence you need to enable static libraries when compiling the boost libraries.

1. Download and unpack the source code
2. boot-strap boost build by executing `./bootstrap.sh`
3. Then execute `b2` with the option `link=static`, for example, I use `./b2 link=static --prefix=/usr/local` and then install the result with `sudo ./b2 link=static --prefix=/usr/local install`

Comment: Where do I then retrieve the `.a` file?

Comment: It's in the `stage/lib` directory in the boost source folder